# Can map variable contains different types

Tags: terraform

Can we pass map variable with multiple var types e.g. `lists[]` & `strings`.

```
identity = {
    type = var.identity.type    
    identity_ids = var.identity.identity_ids
}
```

Working on WebApp module in which I need to pass conditional values for managed user identity.

A identity block supports the following:

type - (Required) Specifies the identity type of the App Service. Possible values are SystemAssigned (where Azure will generate a Service Principal for you), UserAssigned where you can specify the Service Principal IDs in the identity_ids field, and SystemAssigned, UserAssigned which assigns both a system managed identity as well as the specified user assigned identities.

```
identity = {
    type = var.identity.type    
    identity_ids = var.identity.identity_ids
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Terraform Language documentation includes a section [Type Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html) which describes the different ways to specify what types of value are acceptable for module variables.

The kind of type you are looking for here is an *object* type, which differs from a map type in that it specifies an exact set of attributes that are required and what types each of them have. An object type is one of the two [structural type kinds](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#structural-types), and is roughly analogous to a `struct` type in some other languages. Your `identity` variable example might be declared like this:

```
variable "identity" {
  type = object({
    type         = string
    identity_ids = list(string)
  })
}
```

The `{ ... }` syntax that we normally use for constructing maps is actually the object value constructor; object values can automatically convert to map values as long as all of the element types are homogeneous. Therefore the above would accept an expression like you showed in your example, as long as `var.identity.type` were a string and `var.identity.identity_ids` were a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So here when i am trying to pass Identity block to WebApp resource

'
identity = {
    type = "systemassigned"    
    identity_ids = []
  }'

identity.0.identity_ids: attribute supports 1 item as a minimum, config has 0 declared.

Need advice on how i can pass conditional input values for Identity_Ids block as it can be systemassigned or userassigned.